# Place 'floating' contents at the bottom right of a paragraph of text

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ym2GQ/

```css
p {
  background: lightblue;
}

.end {
  background: orange;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam adipiscing orci at tortor bibendum suscipit et eu eros. Nunc congue, ante nec egestas fringilla, ipsum est porttitor leo, tempus lacinia augue erat posuere elit.
</p>
<div class="end">$$</div>
```

I want the floating `$$` to be within the paragraph before it. It should align with the lasts line in the paragraph but it should be floated to right.

How can this be done? Please note that I have to solve this problem under the constraint that I can not float the paragraph element that comes before the div element. I can do whatever I want with the DIV element though. I can also move around the DIV element to some other part of the code if necessary.

Comment: Perhaps position: absolute; it?

Comment: Can't you just move the `div` to before the `p`? Or am I misunderstanding? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ym2GQ/5/

Comment: Just move it before the `<p>` in the source and read http://phrogz.net/CSS/understandingfloats.html

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks for the example. The `$$` needs to be aligned with the last line of the paragraph but floated to right. Is that possible?

Comment: @Phrogz If I do that the `$$` appears on the first line of the paragraph. However, I want it to appear in the last line of the paragraph.

Comment: @Lone That's important information! :) See my answer.

Comment: Why does the div need to be floated? Can you use javascript? If it only needs to show up at the end of the paragraph, you can use position: absolute and place it exactly where you need it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your new information that you want it at the bottom right of the paragraph, see this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/AGEus/1/

[image: Screenshot]

In short:

1. Make the `<div>` a `<span>` and place it as a child of the paragraph.
2. Make the paragraph `position:relative` (so that it establishes its own coordinate system)
3. Put some padding in the paragraph on the right side so that the contents of `.end` won't overlap the text.
4. Absolutely position and size the `.end` to the bottom right of the paragraph.

HTML:

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
  <span class="end">$$</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```css
p      { position:relative; padding-right:2em }
p .end { position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; width:2em }
​
```

Comment: I thought you needed to use a div and not a span?

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the DIV with a SPAN, and moving the  inside the P seems to work.  You can optionally set the SPAN to inline-block depending on the contents.

If you put the SPAN before the text, it will be near the top.  If you put it after, it will be at the bottom.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ym2GQ/6/)

Comment: This shows `$$` on the first line of the paragraph. However, I want it to appear in the last line of the paragraph.

Comment: I wasn't sure from your question, which is why I said you can just move it.  I updated the link to a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, played with your code and found the solution. You need to set the p tag to display: inline and float the div to the right. [I updated your fiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/ym2GQ/14/)

Comment: Note that this can result in `$$` being on its own line after the paragraph (which may or may not be desirable).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want that the div is displayed over your paragraph.
For that you could just set the div to position absolute and set the exact position with top, left, right, bottom.