# Putting an icon at the end of header text

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have a header text in a h1 tag. I'd like to have a small icon at the end of the text (so on the right side of the text)

The text varies in length obviously.

I have set the h1 style to have a background image, no repeat, but it puts it way over to the edge of the div.

Any way I can get it to always line-up at the end of the text? I'm presuming this can't be done with a bg-image like I have tried?

```
h1 {
background-image:url(images/quotemarks.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
h1:after {
    content:url(images/quotemarks.png);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz8hR/)

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden Can you post a screenshot of that? Probably I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden: which browser do you (have to) use? afaik IE < 9 has some problems with pseudo classes

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you, adding a span with an img inside the h1 tag and using some css should give you the results you want... probably...

HTML:

```
<h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<span class="end"><img src='some icon.png'/></span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
    display:inline-block;position:relative; padding-right:2em
}
.end{
    position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; width:2em
}
```

Check out demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aXjzg/2/

More clues can be found here:
[Place 'floating' contents at the bottom right of a paragraph of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320017/place-floating-contents-at-the-bottom-right-of-a-paragraph-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your heading to display inline and set extra padding on the right side to 'contain' the background image.  Trey something like this:

```
<style>
    .h1-with-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    background: url('/image.gif') no-repeat top right;
        }
</style>

<h1 class="h1-with-icon">Heading</h1>
```

See: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tnEhh/1/)

Comment: Could you be more specific?  If you set the display of the h1 ("display: inline-block") it will no longer take up the entire line on the page.  Then, the additional padding you add will move the image to the right of the text.

Comment: Updated with an example for clarity

Comment: Hi. I put the code in your post in. The icon sits in the same place as before (at the very edge of the div, as far as it can go.) So no change from before. No amount of changes to the padding move it. It is still over the very far end and nowhere near the end of the text as hoped.

Comment: Do you have an example of this somewhere that I could take a look at?  If so, I can provide whatever tweaks would be needed to fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any uploaded version (NDA prohibits this). Thanks for your help anyway :(

Comment: If you have a tool like firebug installed, you can take a look at the html element (specifically the H1) and see what styles are affecting it.  The behavior you're describing makes it sound like the H1 is still being affected by a "display: block" somewhere that is overriding the "display: inline-block" you have set.  Firebug can help you identify where that's coming from and fix it :)